# Finding big O of a function

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

How do I find Big O of function which are polynomial fractions

$$f(x) = \frac {x^4 + x^2 + 1}{x^3 + 1}$$

The same question is posted here ([Finding Big-O with Fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428062/finding-big-o-with-fractions)) but i dont understand the explanation on how from the following we concluded that it is order x
$$f(x) = \frac {x^4 + x^2 + 1}{x^3 + 1} 
= \frac{(x^4 + x^2 +1)/x^3}{(x^3 + 1)/x^3}
= \frac{x + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^3}}{1 + \frac{1}{x^3}}$$
and you can prove directly from this that $f(x) = O(x)$.
Also, what are the witness variables for the above proof?

Comment: Do long division to get x+ a proper fraction. Then, note the proper fraction can be bounded by constant for sufficiently large x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from the definition of Big O - $f$ is in $\Theta(x)$ if we can find $c_l$ and $c_u$ such that $c_l x < f(x) < c_u x$ for all $x$ greater than some $x_0$. Try showing this with $c_l = \frac{1}{2} $ and $c_2 = 2$.

EDIT: Sorry, I gave the definition of $f$ is in $\Theta(x)$. $f$ is in $O(x)$ if we can find $c$ such that $f(x) < c x$ for all $x$ greater than some $x_0$.But note that if $f$ is $\Theta(x)$, then it is also $O(x)$ and this function in question is indeed $\Theta(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

For every $x\geqslant1$, $x\leqslant f(x)\leqslant x+1$. Can you conclude?